# I am a process, how much CPU do I consume?

Tags: .net, c#-2.0, process, diagnostics

Is there a way (.net 2.0) for a process to know EXACT amount of processor usage it consumes (something like it would be seen in processexplorer properties/performance graph).

Please, don't go much further then semi-esoteric questions (p-Invoke OK)

Also, so I don't open yet another question - how can I (as a process) control my own affinity - i.e. on which processors (cores) should I be allowed to run?

Comment: +1 for the plain-talkin' title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Process affinity is set using [Process.ProcessorAffinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processoraffinity.aspx).

You can get Process CPU time using [Process.TotalProcessorTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.totalprocessortime.aspx) but I don't know if this gives you the desired granularity and snapshotting ability.

Comment: I guess that's the answer - I just need to measure realtime and divide TotalProcessorTime with it to get my percentage.  Thx.

Comment: @Daniel - yes, you should be able to calculate the delta since last measurement and use that to display something representative. I imagine native code offers better precision though (could be wrong, and f so I will get flamed for this heresy).

Answer (score 1):

Don't invent hot water. Use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394582.aspx).